# HTML Fieldset incorrect JQuery.position in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to move control around inside a fieldset using keydown event, but moving the control 1px up or down in Firefox results in a massive jump down every time you press the up or down key.

I'm using jQuery to get the position of the control and it seems to add either 18 or 20 pixels to the Top property of the position object. In Chrome and IE10 the jQuery method seems to work.

So I tried normal JavaScript, but that seems even worse and I get the same problem in Firefox and Chrome with this.

The first JSFiddle is using jQuery. The second is using normal JavaScript.

[JSFiddle with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/h0Lez69w/7/)

[JSFiddle with plain JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/mfg9hurn/5/)

```
<code>
html:
<label id='Lbl_Position'></label>

<fieldset id='MyFieldSet' style='border: 1px solid black; position:absolute;top:30px; left:30px; width:300px; height: 100px;'>
    <legend>blablablabla</legend>
    <label id='MyLabel'>Some Label</label>
</fieldset>

js:
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#MyFieldSet").resizable();
    $("#MyLabel").css({"position": "absolute", "top": " 20px"});
   $(document)
    .keydown(function (event)
    {
        var $SelectedControl = $("#MyLabel");
        $("#Lbl_Position").text($SelectedControl.position().top);

        if (event.which == '40') // down
        {
            var Top = $SelectedControl.position().top + 1;

            $SelectedControl.css({"top": Top + "px"});
        }
        else if (event.which == '38') // up
        {
            var Top = $SelectedControl.position().top - 1;

            $SelectedControl.css({ "top": Top + "px" });
        }
    });

});
```

I added the resizable so it's as close to my actual work as possible. Am I missing something? Anyone got any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `position()` try using `css()`, it works for me

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#MyFieldSet").resizable();
    $(document).keydown(function(event)
    {
       var pos=parseInt($("#MyLabel").css("top"));

        if (event.which == '40') // down
        {   pos=pos+1;
        }else if (event.which == '38') // up
        {   pos=pos-1;
        }
        $("#Lbl_Position").text(pos);
        $("#MyLabel").css({"top":pos + "px"});
    });

});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h0Lez69w/8/)

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the way to go.